# php mail really slow on mac os x, how do I use postfix/sendmail directly?

Tags: php, macos, email, exec, sendmail

When I use the built in php mail function, the php script hangs for about 20 seconds before continuing. I think it should simply write a file to the postfix queue with the data to be mailed, which should take something like 0.1 seconds instead.

What is the best way to use system / exec to queue an email, alternatively to diagnose and solve the slowness problem?

[See also my question regarding this at serverfault for some details and diagnostic data](https://serverfault.com/questions/358435/php-mail-really-slow-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the the answer you're looking for, but when I had the same issue, I figured out I could just flush the output back to nginx using [fastcgi_finish_request](http://us.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php), and keep the process running until the email is sent.

I see you are using Mac OSX Server, so just switching to nginx might end up causing more trouble than not. In my experience, however, it was well worth the effort.